# Does SQL server provide automatic page repair in the async commit mode AG?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I understand that SQL AG supports the automatic page repair when the primary is synchronized with the secondary.

Suppose the AG is configured in an async commit mode, then does also mean that the primary and secondary are synchronized (I know there would be a delay), there by providing for automatic page repair?

Answer (score 0):

The replica must be SYNCHRONIZED and in a healthy state for the primary to attempt page repair.

Below is what [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/automatic-page-repair-availability-groups-database-mirroring?view=sql-server-ver15) says on the topic.

> On the principal/primary database, automatic page repair is tried only when the database is in the SYNCHRONIZED state and the principal/primary is still sending log records for the database to the mirror/secondary.